# Create session connection

Tags: sql, oracle, asp-classic

I already created a connection to my database. My source code is:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

I want try if else statement

```
if session("myDBtype") = oracle then
Conn.open "DSN=DES1001;UID=DES1001;PWD=Ibs185"
else if
Conn.open "FILEDSN=DES1001.dsn"
end if
```

It displays Syntax error

What is exactly I missing? I already declared session:

```
Session("myDBtype")
myDBtype = "oracle"
```

Comment: You are not comparing a string it should be `if session("myDBtype") = "oracle" then`. `oracle` is not a variable so you will likely get a `variable not defined` error. Your `Session("myDBtype")` contains a string value so when comparing you need to also compare using a string value.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if ...then

else

end if

<%
myDBtype = "oracle"
Session("myDBtype") = myDBtype 

if session("myDBtype") = myDBtype  then
 conn.open "DSN=DES1001;UID=DES1001;PWD=Ibs185"
else
 conn.open "FILEDSN=DES1001.dsn"
end if


%>
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer, *"it should be"* doesn't help anyone. Why *"should it be"*, just posting code doesn't help the community at large.